# Scala for loop Replace on List

Tags: list, scala, type-mismatch

Maybe this might be easy to fix but can you help me out or guide me to a solution. I have a remove function that goes through a List of tuples "List[(String,Any)]" and im trying to replace the 1 index of the value with Nil when the list is being looped over.

But when I try to replace the current v with Nil, it say the v is assigned to "val". Now I understand that scala lists are immutable. So maybe this is what is going wrong?

I tried a Tail recursion implementation as will but when I get out of the def there is a type mismatch. ie: is unit but required: Option[Any]

```
// remove(k) removes one value v associated with key k
// from the dictionary, if any, and returns it as Some(v).  
// It returns None if k is associated to no value.  
def remove(key:String):Option[Any] = {
    for((k,v) <- d){
        if(k == key){
            var temp:Option[Any] = Some(v)
            v = Nil
            return temp
        } 
    }; None
}
```

Here was the other way of trying to figure out

```
  def remove(key:String):Option[Any] = {
    def removeHelper(l:List[(String,Any)]):List[(String,Any)] =
      l match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case (k,v)::t => if (key == k) t else (k,v)::removeHelper(t)
      }
    d = removeHelper(d)
  }
```

Any Suggestions? This is a homework/Project for school thought I might add that for the people that don't like to help with homework.

Comment: Just a note, in the comment it says that the function should 'remove a value associated with the key from the **dictionary**' and then you're using a `List`. Maybe you should consider a `Map` instead, so the code matches the intent? :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are many ways of answering that question. I'll be outlining the ones I can think of here with my own implementations, but the list is by no means exhaustive (nor, probably, the implementations optimal).

First, you can try with existing combinators - the usual suspects are `map`, `flatMap`, `foldLeft` and `foldRight`:

```
def remove_flatMap(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] =
  // The Java developer in me rebels against creating that many "useless" instances.
  list.flatMap {a => if(a._1 == key) Nil else List(a)}

def remove_foldLeft(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] =
  list.foldLeft(List[(String, Any)]()) {(acc, a) =>
    if(a._1 == key) acc
    else            a :: acc
  // Note the call to reverse here.
  }.reverse

// This is more obviously correct than the foldLeft version, but is not tail-recursive.
def remove_foldRight(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] =
  list.foldRight(List[(String, Any)]()) {(a, acc) =>
    if(a._1 == key) acc
    else            a :: acc
  }
```

The problem with these is that, as far as I'm aware, you cannot stop them once a certain condition has been reached: I don't think they solve your problem directly, since they remove *all* instances of `key` rather than the first.

You also want to note that:

- `foldLeft` must reverse the list once it's done, since it appends elements in the "wrong" order.
- `foldRight` doesn't have that flaw, but is not tail recursive: it will cause memory issues on large lists.
- `map` cannot be used for your problem, since it only lets us modify a list's values but not its structure.

You can also use your own implementation. I've included two versions, one that is tail-recursive and one that is not. The tail-recursive one is obviously the better one, but is also more verbose (I blame the ugliness of using a `List[(String, Any)]` rather than `Map[String, Any]`:

```
def remove_nonTailRec(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] = list match {
  case h :: t if h._1 == key => t
  // This line is the reason our function is not tail-recursive.
  case h :: t                => h :: remove_nonTailRec(key, t)
  case Nil                   => Nil
}

def remove_tailRec(key: String, list: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def run(list: List[(String, Any)], acc: List[(String, Any)]): List[(String, Any)] = list match {
    // We've been aggregating in the "wrong" order again...
    case h :: t if h._1 == key => acc.reverse ::: t
    case h :: t                => run(t, h :: acc)
    case Nil                   => acc.reverse
  }

  run(list, Nil)
```

}

The better solution is of course to use the right tool for the job: a `Map[String, Any]`.

Note that I do not think I answer your question fully: my examples *remove* `key`, while you want to set it to `Nil`. Since this is your homework, I'll let you figure out how to change my code to match your requirements.

Comment: +1 you may find a recent blog post I wrote to be a helpful complement for understanding @NicolasRinaudo's suggestions: [Map, reduce, and fold for the programmatically imperative | prose :: and :: conz](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/)

Answer (score 0):

`List` is the wrong collection to use if any key should only exist once.  You should be using `Map[String,Any]`.  With a list,

1. You have to do extra work to prevent duplicate entries.
2. Retrieval of a key will be slower, the further down the list it appears.  Attempting to retrieve a non-existent key will be slow in proportion to the size of the list.

I guess point 2 is maybe why you are trying to replace it with `Nil` rather than just removing the key from the list.  `Nil` is not the right thing to use here, really.  You are going to get different things back if you try and retrieve a non-existent key compared to one that has been *removed*.  Is that really what you want?  How much sense does it make to return `Some(Nil)`, ever?

Here's a couple of approaches which work with mutable or immutable lists, but which don't assume that you successfully stopped duplicates creeping in...

```
val l1: List[(String, Any)] = List(("apple", 1), ("pear", "violin"), ("banana", Unit))
val l2: List[(Int, Any)] = List((3, 1), (4, "violin"), (7, Unit))

def remove[A,B](key: A, xs: List[(A,B)]) = (
  xs collect { case x if x._1 == key => x._2 }, 
    xs map { case x if x._1 != key => x; case _ => (key, Nil) }
)

scala>  remove("apple", l1)
res0: (List[(String, Any)], List[(String, Any)]) = (List((1)),List((apple, List()),(pear,violin), (banana,object scala.Unit)))

scala> remove(4, l2)
res1: (List[(Int, Any)], List[(Int, Any)]) = (List((violin)),List((3,1), (4, List()), (7,object scala.Unit)))

scala> remove("snark", l1)
res2: (List[Any], List[(String, Any)]) = (List(),List((apple,1), (pear,violin), (banana,object scala.Unit)))
```

That returns a list of matching values (so an empty list rather than `None` if no match) and the remaining list, in a tuple.  If you want a version that just completely removes the unwanted key, do this...

```
def remove[A,B](key: A, xs: List[(A,B)]) = (
  xs collect { case x if x._1 == key => x._2 }, 
  xs filter { _._1 != key }
)
```

But also look at this:

```
scala> l1 groupBy {
         case (k, _) if k == "apple" => "removed",
         case _ => "kept"
       }
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, Any)]] = Map(removed -> List((apple,1)), kept -> List((pear,violin), (banana,object scala.Unit)))
```

That is something you could develop a bit.  All you need to do is add `("apple", Nil)` to the "kept" list and extract the value(s) from the "removed" list.

Note that I am using the List combinator functions rather than writing my own recursive code; this usually makes for clearer code and is often as fast or faster than a hand-rolled recursive function.

Note also that I don't change the original list.  This means my function works with both mutable and immutable lists.  If you have a mutable list, feel free to assign my returned list as the new value for your mutable `var`.  Win, win.

But please use a map for this.  Look how simple things become:

```
val m1: Map[String, Any] = Map(("apple", 1), ("pear", "violin"), ("banana", Unit))
val m2: Map[Int, Any] = Map((3, 1), (4, "violin"), (7, Unit))

def remove[A,B](key: A, m: Map[A,B]) = (m.get(key), m - key)

scala> remove("apple", m1)
res0: (Option[Any], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]) = (Some(1),Map(pear -> violin, banana -> object scala.Unit))

scala> remove(4, m2)
res1: (Option[Any], scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Any]) = (Some(violin),Map(3 -> 1, 7 -> object scala.Unit))

scala> remove("snark", m1)
res2: res26: (Option[Any], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]) = (None,Map(apple -> 1, pear -> violin, banana -> object scala.Unit))
```

The combinator functions make things easier, but when you use the right collection, it becomes so easy that it is hardly worth writing a special function.  Unless, of course, you are trying to hide the data structure - in which case you should really be hiding it inside an object.